How to scan over a list of keywords in parquet using polars scan_parquet
I have a parquet file with metadata of categories. I want to scan this parquet file using scan_parquet from polars like below:
filtered_df = (
            pl.scan_parquet(parquet_file)
                .filter(pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("people", literal=True) | pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("nature", literal=True) | pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("urban", literal=True)) | ....
                .filter(pl.col("MAX_WIDTH") >= HORIZONTAL_RES)
                .filter(pl.col("MAX_HEIGHT") >= VERTICAL_RES)
                .collect()
            )

I have a list of categories
['nature, 'people,'urban', ..... 'n_categories]
How do I write the condition of filtering in that scan parquet to go over each category like in the example above. This list is not always fixed since it depends on user input.
I did not try anything since I don't know how to replace this line with a for loop iterating over the categories list.
.filter(pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("people", literal=True) | pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("nature", literal=True) | pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains("urban", literal=True))


Use polars.Expr.str.contains_any.
CATEGORIES = ["people", "nature", "urban", ...]
filtered_df = (
            pl.scan_parquet(parquet_file)
                .filter(pl.col("CATEGORIES").str.contains_any(CATEGORIES))
                .filter(pl.col("MAX_WIDTH") >= HORIZONTAL_RES)
                .filter(pl.col("MAX_HEIGHT") >= VERTICAL_RES)
                .collect()
            )


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
